# how to use Google-analytics-4 in Vue.js 2

Tags: vuejs2, google-analytics-4

Is vue-gtag can be only used in vue3?
then, how can use GA4 in vue2, any references there, or demo code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

vue-gtag 1.16.1 supports ga4 in vue2.

```bash
npm install vue-gtag@1.16.1
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag'
import router from '@/router'

// ...

Vue.use(VueGtag, {
    config: {
        id: 'G-XXXXXXXXXX',
        params: {
            send_page_view: false
        }
    }
}, router)

// ...
```

Comment: `npm install vue-gtag@legacy` will install V 1.x

Answer (score 3):

You can use vue-gtag version 1 which supports vue2.
And also, gtag is not vue spec, it's on javascript spec

Comment: Is there any release notes on specific version that you can point us to, so we can make sure that what you said is true? Docs on the package say vue 3 and up but the package itself is already on v2.*

Comment: @Mishka https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag/tree/1.0

Comment: Thanks Minseo but I do not see what I am looking for. I only see support for UA. 
https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/v/master/

Comment: @Mishka it does support, https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics#does-this-library-support-ga4